# Use MS XSLT functions in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xslt, iis

I am very new to XSLT - have given myself a crash course over the last few days, so my question may well be a bit of a noob one - apologies if so.

Background - I have a PHP page which makes AJAX calls to an external web service. Web service returns XML which I transform using XSLT. My problem, on the surface, is a simple one - I want to reformat the dates in the response to make them UK and user friendly.

My PHP page is hosted on IIS, so I thought I should be able to utilise the MS XSLT function, ms:format-date().

My stylesheet tag at the top is as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
```

and the transformation is done thus:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ms:format-date(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy')"/>
```

Where 'date' in the above is a string in the format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS, but the output instead shows 'false' in the date field.

All I want to be able to do is reformat the date as 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS'

So, my question is - 1, can I use the MS XSLT functions in this was in a PHP based app, and 2, if not, how else can this easily be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can I use the MS XSLT functions in this was in a PHP based app

Probably not, but you can use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="function-available('ms:format-date')"/>
```

to find out for sure.

> if not, how else can this easily be achieved?

There is no format-date() function in XSLT 1.0. Try using a named template instead:

```
<xsl:template name="reformat-dateTime">
    <xsl:param name="dateTime"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="substring($dateTime, 1, 4)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="substring($dateTime, 6, 2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="d" select="substring($dateTime, 9, 2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="time" select="substring($dateTime, 12, 8)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($d, '/', $m, '/', $y, ' ', $time)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Even better. This works perfectly. Just to complete the solution, I replaced the following line: `<xsl:value-of select="ms:format-date(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy')"/>` with `<xsl:call-template name="reformat-dateTime"><xsl:with-param name="dateTime" select="date"/></xsl:call-template>`, and added in thetemplate snippet from @michael shown above just inside the `</xsl:stylesheet>` closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use that Microsoft specific extension function then you would need to use Microsoft's XSLT processor MSXML in PHP on Windows doing something like

```
$doc = new COM('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
doc->async = FALSE;
doc->load('input.xml');
$sheet = new COM('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
$sheet->async = FALSE; $sheet->load('sheet.xsl');
echo $doc->transformNode($sheet);
```

If you use PHP's XSLT processor then you can call into PHP to make use of PHP functions to format a date.

Comment: Thanks Martin. After a little more research I eventually found the PHP XSLTProcessor class [here](http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php). I should have clarified further in my post, but the actual ajax call is made using jquery. The PHP script them formats the web service request and outputs the raw XML, Jquery then applies the transformation in the client, so your example above doesn't really fit without substantial reworking. However, your second suggestion of using XSLTProcessor is much more promising. I am now reworking my XSLT as in the link above

Comment: PHPs XSLTProcessor supports EXSLT, too. That includes the [EXSLT date functions](http://exslt.org/date/index.html).